# Compose key not working

Tags: arch-linux, x11, xkb, compose-key

I added `setxkbmap -option "compose:ralt"` to my `.xinitrc` to map the right alt key as the compose key (Multi_key) and copied the default `.XCompose` file to my home directory.

Why is the compose key now not working, when I for example try to write `#`  with the defined key combination `right alt`+`+`+`+` nothing happens.

Here is that default line in the `.XCompose` file:

```
<Multi_key> <plus> <plus>           : "#"   numbersign # NUMBER SIGN
```

Why is it not working? What is the best way to check if the compose key is set the right way?
I'm running arch linux with X and i3wm as the window manager.

---

Running `xev` and using that key shows that output:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x2c00001,
    root 0x13c, subw 0x0, time 1833869, (0,52), root:(964,91),
    state 0x8, keycode 108 (keysym 0xffea, Alt_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

So my computer detects the `ALT_R` key. Does that mean the problem arch does not see it as the compose key?

Comment: Run `xev` from a terminal and press RAlt in the xev window. What KeyPress event appears in the terminal?

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: So that `setxkbmap` call doesn't seem to have had any effect. Does it work if you run it from a terminal after logging in? Are you sure that it got executed as part of your login scripts? Maybe something else in your configuration overrides it afterwards — that's a common issue people have with some desktop environments, though it would be less likely to happen with a simple window manager, but still do check.

Comment: I did not use my computer a few days, but after starting it today the compose key magically works. I rebooted the computer after changing my `.xinit` file, so another reboot today should not be the reason. I can't explain why it is working now.